# QFT: What does "finiteness" mean?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, renormalization

As above: what is the definition of a QFT to be "finite"?

1. That all UV corrections are finite and there are **no divergences at all**?
2. That there are divergences, but these divergences can be **absorbed** in the (suppose renormalisable) Lagrangian with counterterms, leaving just a finite quantum correction?

Comment: Closely related, and maybe even a duplicate: [“finite” QFTs and short-distance singularities and vanishing beta functions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27244/)

Comment: Related, but I need just a Yes/No answer.

Comment: Ok, solved thanks to a video lecture by Cachazo: "being just renormalisable is for losers, being finite is better!"